# Slidebars jQuery not working on mobile - links won't open

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

I'm struglling to get the links in my slidebar overlay menu to go to their respective pages.
Running on Android, when tested with responsivator all works, but when I test on my phone the links don't go where they should.

Test site is http://studiochem.com/test

```
<div class="sb-open-left"><a href="#">Menu</a></div>

<section id="content">
    <img src="http://studiochem.com/2015/sweetpea/images/shop.png">
    <p>%CATEGORY_VERTICAL%</p>
    <img src="http://studiochem.com/2015/sweetpea/images/info.png">
    <p>%PAGES_VERTICAL%</p>
    <img src="http://studiochem.com/2015/sweetpea/images/cart.png">
    <p align="center">%VIEW_CART%   </p>

</section>


$(".menu a").on('click', function(){
$.slidebars.close()
section = $(this).attr('href')
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
}, 2000);
})
```

Comment: what phone are you testing on android or iphone?

Comment: Hi, and android phone.

Comment: gonna hand it to you, that's odd!

Comment: this is a z-indexing issue almost certainly, I am just trying to trace back where the issue is exactly. your stylesheet has lot going on

Comment: Thank you, I know, it's a bit all over the place at the moment as I fumble my way around.

Comment: is sb-slider code you wrote or something that has a working demo and documentation? nevermind, i found it!

Comment: you have me stumped. I really recommend you contact the plugin developer. http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars/contact.php

Comment: I have and am awaiting a response, but thank you so much for taking the time to look at it for me, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The plugin you're using responds to "touchend", which is why your own code would work on an emulator that uses mouse events but not on a device that uses touch (which can be emulated using the Chrome emulator by the way). Adding `touchend` to the event seems to fix it.

```
$(".menu a").on('click touchend', function(){
$.slidebars.close()
section = $(this).attr('href')
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(section).offset().top
}, 2000);
})
```

Comment: Great! Happy to help :)